# Convert 3D surface data to 2D range image

Tags: matlab, 3d, triangulation, point-clouds

I have a 3D surface represented using a wrl file. I have read the required info. from the file and have the following data : vertices, faces, normals, texture coordinates.

How do I use these data to convert this to a 2D range image (which is the same as a normal intensity image but with the exception that each pixel carries a depth value of the underlying surface) ? I prefer a Matlab-favored solution to the problem, although general ideas are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Use `griddata`

If I understood correctly you have x,y,z data and you want to convert it to an image, where image intensity is Z.

```
[ximg,yimg]=meshgrid(1:szX,1:szY);
img = griddata(x,y,z,ximg,yimg); 
% normalize image, or set it at range you want
```

I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Ander. I tried that first (sorry I forgot to mention that in the post). But an important constraint in griddata is that the grid points (from meshgrid) must be part of the 3D surface we are interpolating from. In my case, the 3D data I have are centered elsewhere(most of the x-y points are negative). To perform this, I am trying to recenter the 3D point cloud I have (by merely translating) to approximately the center of the grid obtained from meshgrid. What do you think of this ?

Comment: @Swami Definetly. You should 1: Pad all your X-Y data to be centered at szX/2 szY/2, and then 2: scale the data so the vertices  are all in range 1:szX 1:szY (included). It shodl be too dificut I think ;)